# cakephp 2.x: Make some dropdown required or not with a dynamic name

Tags: jquery, cakephp, select, required

I found some posts related to my issue but not as I was looking for. So I ask for your help. Some of them are required but not all of them (and more, the user can add some drop-down list and edit the name, so we never know in advance).

I have many drop-down list like below with a dynamic name.

```
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                    <?php    
                        echo $this->Form->input('rate-'.$refs[$i]['Reference']['id'], array(
                                'id'        => $refs[$i]['Reference']['id'],
                                'label'     => false,
                                'type'      => 'select',
                                'options'   => $rate,
                                'class'     => 'form-control selectpicker',
                                'empty'     => '-- RATE --',
                            ));
                    ?> 

                </div>
```

I tried the following (with database information) but it's not working :

```
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                    <?php    
                        echo $this->Form->input('rate-'.$refs[$i]['Reference']['id'], array(
                                'id'        => $refs[$i]['Reference']['id'],
                                'label'     => false,
                                'type'      => 'select',
                                'options'   => $rate,
                                'class'     => 'form-control selectpicker',
                                'empty'     => '-- RATE --',
                                'required'     => $required,
                            ));
                    ?> 

                </div>
```

May I do something wrong ? Do you have any idea on how to get this ?

Thank you

Comment: It seems you need to dynamically add/change validation rules, reading this might help: [Dynamically change validation rules](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules)

Comment: I actually don't receive any errors. But as Roman said, I might change the rules dynamically. I will try and let you know in a while.

Comment: So it's not working. I don't find the way to get the dynamic name...
I tried to use the validator->add in my model, but as I don't the field name in advance...

Note: I use the bootstrap select as plugin. I also checked this [help](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-select/) but always the same issue with the name...

Any ideas ? (thanks in advance for your help)

Comment: I tried [this solution](http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2013/08/dynamic-fields-validation-in-cakephp.html) but it's not working...and I don't have any error message...I think I do something wrong....Any ideas or a way to solve this issue ?